# what is diffrence between "$var" and "${var}"

Tags: bash, shell-script

i have seen in many script usage of `"$var"` and `"${var}"`, so I just want to know diffrence between `"$var"` and `"${var}"`

Answer (score 5):

The braces explicitly denote the beginning and end of the parameter syntax, otherwise, there is no difference. This makes certain statements unambiguous, for example:

```
$ foo=bar
$ echo "$fooa" # Is this $foo + a, or $fooa?

$ echo "${foo}a"
bara
```

Comment: but i can use `echo "$foo"a` then why braces in used?

Comment: @RahulPatil Then there is no difference. `"` is an illegal character in a variable name, so it terminates there.

Comment: @RahulPatil But, with the braces you can do a lot more! See also the link provided by manatwork in the comment to your question.

Comment: There's no ambiguity in the first statement - It's clearly the value of the `fooa` variable. Bash is not DWIM-compatible :)

Comment: @l0b0 - perhaps I should have said "ambiguous to humans", obviously the actual syntax is defined ;-)